# Difference between assigning null to Map and FastMap instance to Map

Tags: java, collections

Actually, I am just trying to read image properties/ Image through

```
 ImageTransform.getBufferedImage(path, locale)
```

and putting the return values in a Map as below:

```
     1. Map<String, Object> imgBfr = null;
        imgBfr.putAll(ImageTransform.getBufferedImage(path, locale));
```

When I try the above I am getting exceptions. But If try the following, it works perfectly.

```
     2. Map<String, Object> imgBfr = FastMap.newInstance();
        imgBfr.putAll(ImageTransform.getBufferedImage(objectInfo, locale));
```

What makes difference. Can any one please give a brief differences between above two.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the fact that you actually have a `Map` instance in case 2 makes the difference

Comment: According to you, what happens if you attempt to dereference a null reference?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the *reference* to `null`

```
Map<String, Object> imgBfr = null;
```

so you can't invoke a method on this this (*what* are you invoking on if it's `null`?)

In your second scenario you give yourself a new map instance:

```
Map<String, Object> imgBfr = FastMap.newInstance();
```

and so you have a valid (non-null reference to invoke upon.

Comment: Yeah. Got it. I could think once. Thank you for immediate response.